# How to select the most distinct value or How to perform a Inner/Nested groupBy in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Original Dataframe

```
+-------+---------------+
| col_a |       col_b   |
+-------+---------------+
|    1  |          aaa  |
|    1  |          bbb  |
|    1  |          ccc  |
|    1  |          aaa  |
|    1  |          aaa  |
|    1  |          aaa  |
|    2  |          eee  |
|    2  |          eee  |
|    2  |          ggg  |
|    2  |          hhh  |
|    2  |          iii  |
|    3  |          222  |
|    3  |          333  |
|    3  |          222  |
+-------+---------------+
```

Result Dataframe I needed

```
+----------------+---------------------+-----------+
| group_by_col_a | most_distinct_value | col_a cnt |
+----------------+---------------------+-----------+
|             1  |          aaa        |     6     |
|             2  |          eee        |     5     |
|             3  |          222        |     3     |
+----------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Here is what I have tried so far

```
val DF = originalDF
.groupBy($"col_a")
.agg(
max(countDistinct("col_b"))
count("col_a").as("col_a_cnt"))
```

and error msg.
**org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: It is not allowed to use an aggregate function in the argument of another aggregate function. Please use the inner aggregate function in a sub-query.**

what is the problem? 
Is there an efficient method to select the most distinct value?

Comment: what is the logic behind your output dataframe?

Comment: I mean most duplicate values

Comment: and what "col_a cnt" mean just count about col_a, I think it is work. @RameshMaharjan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two `groupBy` for this and a `join` to get the results as below

```
  import spark.implicits._


  val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    (1, "aaa"), (1, "bbb"),
    (1, "ccc"), (1, "aaa"),
    (1, "aaa"), (1, "aaa"),
    (2, "eee"), (2, "eee"),
    (2, "ggg"), (2, "hhh"),
    (2, "iii"), (3, "222"),
    (3, "333"), (3, "222")
  )).toDF("a", "b")

  //calculating the count for coulmn a
  val countDF = data.groupBy($"a").agg(count("a").as("col_a cnt"))

  val distinctDF = data.groupBy($"a", $"b").count()
    .groupBy("a").agg(max(struct("count","b")).as("max"))
  //calculating and selecting the most distinct value 
    .select($"a", $"max.b".as("most_distinct_value"))
  //joining both dataframe to get final result
    .join(countDF, Seq("a"))

  distinctDF.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-------------------+---------+
|  a|most_distinct_value|col_a cnt|
+---+-------------------+---------+
|  1|                aaa|        6|
|  3|                222|        3|
|  2|                eee|        5|
+---+-------------------+---------+
```

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, you can do the conversion using `RDD` level. Because `RDD` level conversion much faster the `DataFrame` level.

```
val input = Seq((1, "aaa"), (1, "bbb"), (1, "ccc"), (1, "aaa"), (1, "aaa"),
    (1, "aaa"), (2, "eee"), (2, "eee"), (2, "ggg"), (2, "hhh"), (2, "iii"),
    (3, "222"), (3, "333"), (3, "222"))

import sparkSession.implicits._

val inputRDD: RDD[(Int, String)] = sc.parallelize(input)
```

convertion:

```
val outputRDD: RDD[(Int, String, Int)] =
    inputRDD.groupBy(_._1)
      .map(row =>
        (row._1,
          row._2.map(_._2)
            .groupBy(identity)
            .maxBy(_._2.size)._1,
          row._2.size))
```

Now, you can create data frame and display.

```
val outputDf: DataFrame = outputRDD.toDF("col_a", "col_b", "col_a cnt")
outputDf.show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+-----+---------+
|col_a|col_b|col_a cnt|
+-----+-----+---------+
|    1|  aaa|        6|
|    3|  222|        3|
|    2|  eee|        5|
+-----+-----+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your requirement by simply defining a `udf` function, using `collect_list` function and `count` function (which you've already done)

In `udf` function, you can send the *collected list* of `col_b` values and return the *max occuring string* in the group as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def maxCountdinstinct =  udf((list: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => {
                                list.groupBy(identity)                 // grouping with the strings
                                  .mapValues(_.size)                   // counting the grouped strings
                                  .maxBy(_._2)._1                      // returning the string with max count
                              }
                            )
```

And you can call the `udf` function as

```
val DF = originalDF
  .groupBy($"col_a")
  .agg(maxCountdinstinct(collect_list("col_b")).as("most_distinct_value"), count("col_a").as("col_a_cnt"))
```

which should give you

```
+-----+-------------------+---------+
|col_a|most_distinct_value|col_a_cnt|
+-----+-------------------+---------+
|3    |222                |3        |
|1    |aaa                |6        |
|2    |eee                |5        |
+-----+-------------------+---------+
```

Comment: finally `orderBy` col_a to get the result.

Comment: @RumeshKrish, ordering should not matter just to save or show in a distributed processing unless you want to do some specific processing in order. :)

Comment: Exactly. I like the way you defined `udf` function. :)

Comment: great to hear that @RumeshKrish and thanks for the upvote :) really appreciate that.